# Dart equivalent to get an element of a sequence and transform it fluently through a pipeline

Tags: dart

What is Dart equivalent to get an element of a sequence and transform it with a `map()` fluently through a pipeline.

Something like doing in Java streams:

```java
var result = ....findFirst().map(elem -> transform(elem)).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really make much sense to have a "pipeline" for a single event (if that was what you mean by the `findFirst()` call). But if you want to, you can combine something with `where()` and `take()` so you keep the `Iterable` and therefore be able to use `map` on it:

```
void main() {
  print(
    [1, 2, 3]
        .where((element) => element == 2)
        .take(1) // Could also be skipped because of .first later
        .map((e) => e.toRadixString(2))
        .map((e) => e.padLeft(8, '0'))
        .map((e) => 'Number in binary is: $e')
        .first,
  ); // Number in binary is: 00000010
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine. Yet, IMHO is at least controversial to say that a "_pipeline" for a single event_" "_does not really make much sense_". There are a lot of examples of monadic implementations of a single event that provide chaining ability, such as `Mono`, `Optional`, `Single`, `Maybe`, `Deferred`, `CompletableFuture`, and many others.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa And I am talking about this from a Dart perspective where we have `Iterable` and `Stream` with the `map` method. An `Iterable` with a single event is not something I personally finds useful in many scenarios. :)